# Unexpected font size change in Android at the level of decimals

Tags: android, fonts, size, decimal

I noticed that when the font size is specified with setTextSize method in android textview, the decimals of the font size were determined based on resolution and I realized this by using getTextSize method.

I'm working on a project with a very high font sensitivity. There has to be absolutely zero change in the positioning and the size of the components in this project.

For instance, when I specify a font size such as 30.777777777, I don't want Android to make any changes to that.

Actual sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.magazinetest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAMPLE TEXT"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAMPLE TEXT"
        android:textSize="40.2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Exactly same result: There is no change between **40 dp** and **40.2 dp**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4s2c.png

Is there any way to prevent that?

Note: IOS doesn't make such a change to the font size.

Comment: I don't get what you meant by android changing the font size by itself. Can you give me a reproducible piece of code that demonstrates this?

Comment: i added the sample code and image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set textsize in `dp`. Changes may happen if you set textsize in `sp`. Read documentation [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)